# Lua: gmatch multi line string?

Tags: lua, string-matching

I'm trying to make a function that searches through some code to find the line the search term is on, as well as the line's index. The code is a multi line string with new line characters. I was thinking of using gmatch to do this, but I have no clue how.

This is my code at the moment. It's awful, but I can't think of a way to make it any better:

```
local function search( code, term )
  local matches = {}
  local i = 0
  for line in string.gmatch( code, "[^\r\n]+" ) do
    i = i + 1
    if string.find( line, term, 1, true ) then
      table.insert( matches, { line = i, code = line } )
    end
  end
  return matches
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To correctly count empty lines: `for line in string.gmatch( code, "([^\r\n]*)\r?\n?" ) do`

Comment: Why do you find this code is awful?

Comment: @lhf it goes through every single line one by one just to see if one of the lines has the correct string, rather than looking at the lines as a whole, which I feel it could as it's a single string. Also, the part where I add 1 to I feels wrong. I'm used to k and v when looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seem fine to me. The problem with using a single `gmactch` loop is your requirement to report line numbers. The code below avoids this by embedding line numbers into the code. I've use `@` to mark line numbers. You can use any char that does not appear in the source code, even something like `\0`.

```
function search(code,term)
    for a,b in code:gmatch("@(%d+):([^\n]-"..term.."[^\n]-)\n") do
        print(a)
        print(b)
    end
end

local n=0
code="\n"..code
code=code:gsub("\n", function () n=n+1 return "\n@"..n..":" end)

search(code,"matc")
```